# windows11 installation: can't read my storage - need storage driver

Tags: drivers, installation, windows-11, nvme, samsung-ssd

I want to install Windows 11 on my system. But it wants a storage driver and it can't read my storage (in partitioning level).

My storage is a Samsung MZVLQ1T0HBLB-00B00 nvme ssd (asus tuf dash f15).

What should I do or what driver do I need?

Comment: Driver here possibly>>>https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/

Comment: i downloaded that driver and copied it in my flash drive (bootable windows11 media). but when i select the flash drive it saying : no signed driver were find

Comment: You should go to ASUS or Intel and get the IRST driver.

Comment: Do you have Windows 10 currently installed? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc yeah. .

Comment: Strange - if upgrading from within Windows 10, all the drivers should already be there.

Comment: Does your computer support Windows 11? My first guess is that while you're seeing something about the OS not recognizing the storage, the real issue is deeper. I'd start by updating BIOS and perhaps resetting it to make sure the storage options there are defaulted. I'd also make sure the SSD firmware is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find your IRST driver for your laptop and put it in your Windows bootable USB.

If you get error, that it can`t find signed driver, than go one folder deeper. I get the same error, because driver was extracted in folder. So you need to set driver folder that was extracted by driver installation, not that folder where you extracted it.

Posted this answer, because I saw in comments that someone was facing the same problem with no signed driver error.